# Дерево NESTED SETS в Json

Tags: php, json, nested-sets

Помогите решить задачу, а то что я додуматься не могу как правильно сделать. Смотрите, я делаю запрос на базу данных, и получаю таблицу (таблица структуры NESTED SETS), таблицу можно увидеть на картинке.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Делаю запрос

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM geo WHERE geo.lft >= 2 ORDER BY geo.lft';
$result= DB::fetchAll($sql);
```

Я получаю массив данных, мне этот массив нужно так переделать, что бы при кодировании в json вышел такой формат:

```
    [
  {
    text: "Parent 1",
    icon:"glyphicon glyphicon-unchecked",
    nodes: [
      {
        text: "Child 1",
        icon:"glyphicon glyphicon-unchecked",
        nodes: [
          {
            text: "Grandchild 1",
            icon:"glyphicon glyphicon-unchecked"
          },
          {
            text: "Grandchild 2",
            icon:"glyphicon glyphicon-unchecked"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        text: "Child 2",
        icon:"glyphicon glyphicon-unchecked"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    text: "Parent 2",
    icon:"glyphicon glyphicon-unchecked"
  }
]
```

В text нужно вставить названия географического объекта, то есть $result[$index]['name'] .

Answer (score 0):

Проще всего использовать готовую библиотеку для работы с деревьями. Как вариант: http://www.sesmikcms.ru/pages/read/biblioteka-dlja-raboty-s-derevjami-nested-sets/

Я ее не использовал, но идея что гуглить думаю будет вам понятна.